# Saving a plot into a png file in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, png

I have created a simple plot in Python using matplotlib.pyplot. The code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bumpy as np
@np.vectorize
def f(x):
    return x
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'r')
plt.show()
```

Now I would like to save that plot into a png file and I am to use plt.savefig(). I tried to do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bumpy as np
@np.vectorize
def f(x):
    return x
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'r')    
plt.show(block = False)
plt.savefig("plot.png", format = 'png')
```

There is no error but unfortunately it doesn't work. How can I use plt.savefig() properly?

Comment: Try removing the `plt.show(block = False)` statement if you only want to save the figure and not show it.

Comment: @nanoPhD But I need to show that figure too. And then I would like to save it.

Comment: @nanoPhD I tried to use some of those solutions - unfortunately no success.

Comment: `plt.savefig()` needs to be called before `plt.show()`, just like the duplicate explains.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That worked! Thanks :)